# Change the content for first tab from another

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have 2 tabs , both with slide out menu . 
I want that when i am in the second tab , and i select a cell from menu to change the content of the first tab.

I was trying to do this with delegate , but  nothing is changing.

So, in my second tab .h i have :

```
@protocol feedDelegate

@required
-(void)parseJson:(NSString *)urlPlaylist;
@end

@interface FavoriteViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) id delegate;
```

and in .m :

```
 if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(parseJson:)])
    {

        self.tabBarController.selectedViewController=[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
       [_delegate parseJson:urlPl];
       [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reload_data" object:self];

            }
```

In first tab i set :

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <feedDelegate>
```

If condition is true , but the content from the first view is not changing .

```
-(void)parseJson:(NSString *)urlPlaylist{

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlPlaylist];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    NSURLResponse *response = NULL;
    NSError *requestError = NULL;

    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&requestError];

    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];



    NSData* jsonData = [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSError *jsonError;
    NSArray * allKeys = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&jsonError];

    titleVideo =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    images =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    titleVideo = [allKeys valueForKey:@"items" ];
    titleVideo=[titleVideo valueForKey:@"snippet"];
    keys=[titleVideo valueForKey:@"resourceId"];
    keys=[keys valueForKey:@"videoId"];

    images=[titleVideo valueForKey:@"thumbnails"];
    images=[images valueForKey:@"default"];
    images=[images valueForKey:@"url"];
    description=[titleVideo valueForKey:@"description"];
    titleVideo=[titleVideo valueForKey:@"title"];


}
```

The problem is that when the reload is call , the values of this array it's changed.

Comment: check "reload_data" method is going to call or not.

Comment: yes it's calling , but i don't know why the values are the old. I update my question.

Comment: Are you doing it on main thread ?

Comment: Have you tried to call `setNeedsDisplay` method explicitly ?

Comment: No . Could you help with how i should do it or where ?